# passar valor do input text pra uma função do angular

Tags: angular

Alguém poderia me ajudar a  passar o conteudo de um input text pra uma função no angular?

meu html é:

```
 <form class= "form mt-4">

<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{ 'buscaAtestado' | translate }}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <div class="text-center mb-3">
        <i class="fa fa-search mr-2"></i>
        <input  [value]="filter"  class= "rounded mb-3" type="search" placeholder="search..." autofocus>
        <section fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap class="container" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutGap.xs="20px">
            <button type="button" mat-raised-button class="download" (click)="baixarTodos()">{{ 'baixarAtestados' | translate}}</button>
            <button type="reset" mat-raised-button class="limpar" (click)="onClean()"> {{ 'limpar' | translate }}</button>
            <button type="submit" mat-raised-button class="pesquisar" (click)="onSearch()">{{ 'pesquisar' | translate }}</button>
        </section>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

e o meu component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-atestado',
templateUrl: './atestado.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./atestado.component.scss']
})
export class AtestadoComponent implements OnInit {


filter: string= '';


constructor(
    private projetoService: ProjetoService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {


}

onSearch(){
    console.log(this.filter)
}
```

Comment: O melhor seria vc usar o ngModel ou o reactiveForms

Answer (score 2):

**Olá viva, uma forma de aceder ao input pode ser como o respondida anteriormente, com 2 way binding.**

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="filtro" name ="filtro" class= "rounded mb-3" type="search" placeholder="search..." autofocus>
```

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
templateUrl: './test.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {


private filtro: string= '';


constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {
}
}
```

**Outra alternativa:**

```
<input #myInput  [(ngModel)]="filtro" name ="filtro" class= "rounded mb-3" type="search" placeholder="search..." autofocus>
```

```
import { Component,Inject,ViewChild,ElementRef,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
templateUrl: './test.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild('myInput') myInput:ElementRef; 
private filtro: string= '';

constructor() {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.value);
    }
}
```

**Angular 8, na opção com ViewChild, adicionar o parametro static:**

```
@ViewChild('myInput', {static: true}) myInput:ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

funcionou com o ngModel e faltou atribuir o name a tag

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="filtro" name ="filtro" class= "rounded mb-3" type="search" placeholder="search..." autofocus>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar FormGroup e FormBuilder? Sempre uso e não tem erro. Qualquer coisa eu informo o código.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro voce precisa inserir algum evento no seu template, para esse caso o evento "onchange".

```
<input type="search" (change)="//seu methodo" />
```

Feito isso, insira o seu metodo com o parametro que deseja passar para ele.

#### Exemplos

Passando um valor fixo:

```
 <input type="search" (change)="onSelect('foo')" />
```

definindo uma variavel para o seu elemento e resgatando os valores do mesmo, exemplo:

```
<input type="search" #mySearch (change)="onSearch(mySearch.value)" />
```

resgatando o elemeto em si:

```
// no template
<input type="search" (change)="onSearch($event)" />

// na sua classe:
onSearch(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
}
```